# Progresa/Oportunidades dataset

Tags: data-request, latin-america, randomized-trial

[Progresa/Oportunidades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oportunidades) is a large scale social welfare program that was conducted as an RCT and that has been widely evaluated (for a list of econ papers using this data see [here](https://ideas.repec.org/cgi-bin/htsearch?ul=%25%2Fa%2F%25&q=Progresa&cmd=Search!&wf=4BFF&s=R&dt=range&db=&de=&m=all&fmt=long&sy=1&ps=10)).

When trying to find the data sources, links (e.g. on [dataverse.harvard.edu](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=hdl:1902.1/18235)) point to a website that doesn't exist: http://evaluacion.oportunidades.gob.mx:8010/en/index.php

There is [main website](http://evaluacion.oportunidades.gob.mx:8010/EVALUACION/index1.php) has a "Databases" link, but provides just a bunch on individual datasets, without a clean documentation, and apparently **without the data on treatment assignment.**

Hence my question: Does anyone know of a reliable source for pre-compiled Proresa data including the treatment indicator and post-treatment outcomes?

Edit: Data should be on the household/individual level

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem and was wondering whether you ever found a relatively cleaned-up dataset, or another way to figure out the household's treatment status (whether it was included in the treatment or control group of Progesa's initial 1997-1999 period)? This would be extremely helpful! Thanks.

Comment: I had figured it out at some point but unfortunately don't have the data anymore. I only remember that after several hours of crawling through different sources I finally figured it out and it wasn't  all that hard. Sorry that I can only give you this unhelpful answer rn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wayback Machine has this indexed a few times. Remember, when dealing with linkrot, the Wayback Machine is your friend:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150421004546/http://evaluacion.oportunidades.gob.mx:8010/index1.php

Edit:
Why would it not give you access to the data? I can only think of a few occasions where this would be the case, and in this one, it is not. All you had to do was look...

Better Edit:
The data you seek is here: https://www.prospera.gob.mx/EVALUACION/index1.php
From navigation: Evaluation and Indicators -> External Evaluation Reports & Studies -> Oportunidades
Double clicking on each datasets' header (colored background) displays dropdown with data for downloading.
You can compare the original 2003 docs to current, they are the same:
[2003 Original](https://web.archive.org/web/20101031083632/http://evaluacion.oportunidades.gob.mx:8010/en/docs/eval_docs_2003.php)
[2003 Current](https://www.prospera.gob.mx/EVALUACION/en/docs/docs2003.php)

Comment: While this is helpful in getting some more info, it doesn't give me access to the data, does it?

Comment: Sorry, I might be blind, but I really don't  see where the actual dataset  are in there. I'm not interested in downloading the reports. I want the datatset, with households/individual variables and treatment indicators. Under the link you posted I only see a bunch of PDFs. Is this the link you meant: http://imgur.com/YczRPNq?

Comment: the pdf has data, you're gonna have to extract it. i'm looking at a table on page 271 / 336 in the pdf.

Comment: Well. Given that this is a highly (over-)researched dataset, I expect there are cleaner versions of that data around. Besides page 271 has just some aggregates, which is clearly not what I'm searching for.

Comment: there may be...no clue. but that's the original set.

Comment: pages 43-70ish (Anex A, Anex B) have data tables. i realize this isn't neatly packaged, but this is what you asked for, the data is all there. extracting it is relatively painless with the right tools.

Comment: You keep repeating that this is the data I was asking for. But it is not. I clearly asked for "data including the treatment indicator and post-treatment outcomes?". While not explicitly stating that the granularity, "treatment indicator" clearly implies that the data I'm looking for should be at least on the level of treatment assignment. Which is not the case for the aggregates presented in the pdfs, also not the tables on pages 43-70.

Comment: i missed the clearly asked for part. looks like you've done a little editing to the question there...treatment indicator implies something to you. what is clear is that you cannot be bothered to deep dive into the pdf. even though this is a "highly(over-)researched dataset", the data is not online....just trying to help. i don't speak spanish, nor can i read minds.

Comment: Sorry, I was not very cooperative. Your answer was just not very helpful and "All you had to do was look" didn't help my mood, as that's what I'm doing since weeks, without success.

It is not true that I can't be bothered with the PDFs, it's just that they do not contain the information I seek.

Yes, I tried to make my question clearer, the "treatment indicator" part was there from the beginning but now I explicitly state the desired granularity.

Comment: no problem. i get grouchy too. hope you find what you want.